# Read lines in Fortran 77 and cast strings to numbers

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
7000
1.54
-0.32
```

What I'd like to do is to read from file, line by line, and assign each of the numbers to a numerical variable. There are always 3 lines with numbers, but I don't know the length of numbers. They may be integer, float, negative. How can I achieve this?

And for the Fortran 77. Yeah, I know. But it's not my call to use it.

Comment: if you tried the most basic read statement in f77 i think you'll discover it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for reading in your file:

```
integer :: i
real    :: a, b

open( file='filename.txt', unit=1234, status='old' )
read(1234,*) i
read(1234,*) a
read(1234,*) b
close(1234)
```

And this is for casting a string to `real` using internal I/O:

```
character(len=10) :: str = '1.23e1'
real    :: a

read(str,*) a
```

Comment: This will work reliably if the input file contains one integer followed by two reals.  I interpreted the question to mean that a real or an integer might occur in any line of the input file.

Comment: Then I would suggest reading in `reals` only, and rounding them to `integers` if required. This is just an example...

Comment: if you need to discern wheter a value is an integer or a float equal to an integer (7000 vs 7000.) its a bit more interesting, I didnt get that requirement from the question though.